# Overloading operator << for enum causes repeated output

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading

I am trying to create an `enum` and do output operator overloading to print out this `enum` directly, but its not working.  All I am getting is the following screenshot

[image]

And the code that produces it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

enum KeyboardLayout
{
 arabic, chinese, english, french, german
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, KeyboardLayout& k)
{
  out<<"(keyboard layout: "<< k << ")"<<endl;

  return out;
}

int main()
{

KeyboardLayout k=english;

cout<<k;


return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong here?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? You print the enum, which prints "(keyboard layout:" and then print the enum, which prints "(keyboard layout:" and then prints the enum, which prints "(keyboard layout:" and then prints the enum, which ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an infinite recursion going on

```
cout<<k;
```

calls `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, KeyboardLayout& k)`.  Then you have

```
out<<"(keyboard layout: "<< k << ")"<<endl;
```

in the function which calls `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, KeyboardLayout& k)` all over again.  As you can see this will never end.

You need to have a `switch` statement or `if` blocks and depending on what `k` is print out a string that is the same as the value it holds.  Something like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, KeyboardLayout& k)
{
  out<<"(keyboard layout: ";

  switch(k)
  {
    case arabic: out << "arabic"; break;
    case chinese: out << "chinese"; break;
    case english: out << "english"; break;
    case french: out << "french"; break;
    case german: out << "german"; break;
  }

  out << ")"<<endl;

  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[@NathanOliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35139784/3093378) is perfectly correct. My answer is a quick and dirty fix: perform a cast on `k` when invoking `operator<<`:

```
out<<"(keyboard layout: "<< static_cast<int>(k) << ")"<<endl;
```

The net effect will be that the compiler will invoke the generic `operator<<`, because it is a better match.

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af8c36c8bb48d423)

Comment: `+k` also works, and has the benefit of being shorter and working regardless of the underlying type of the enum, if somewhat less obvious.

Comment: well this would result in printing the numerical value of the enun not the actual value i entered.

Comment: @Mina `enum`s don't have a string value, they are represented as numbers internally. If you need to print e.g. "english", then you need a `switch`.

Comment: @AlanStokes Can you remind me what `+` does? Rvalue conversion to `int`? I always forget this trick.

Comment: @vsoftco: Unary + is a no-op on a positive value aside from the integral promotion (so, yes)

Comment: @vsoftco It just applies the usual numeric promotion rules to the operand. Really handy when that's what you want; shame it's so mysterious, especially for unsigned types.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's a no-op on negative values too. And zero.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And I didn't suggest it was ;-)